# django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch at /home/

Tags: django, django-templates, django-urls

I have problem when I visit `localhost:8000/home`:

> Powershell: django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'register' not found. 'register' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

html:

```
<section>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-dark navbar-dark ">
      <!-- Container wrapper -->
      <div class="container-fluid justify-content-center">
        <!-- Navbar brand -->
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'home_page' %}"> Turbine Power Web</a>

          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
                {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'accounts:logout' %}">Logout</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'accounts:password_change' %}">Change Password</a></li>
                {% else %}
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'accounts:login' %}">Login</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'accounts:user-registration' %}">Register</a></li>
                {% endif %}
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="">Turbine Models</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="">Author</a></li>
                {% if user.is_company %}
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="">My Models</a></li>
                {% endif %}
                    <li class="nav-item"> Hello, {{ user.username|default:'Guest' }} </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <!-- Navbar -->
</section>
```

**views.py**

```
def home_page(request):
    return render(request, 'turbineweb/home_page.html')
```

project **urls.py**

```
    urlpatterns = [
        path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
        path('', include('accounts.urls', namespace='accounts')),
        path('', include('turbineweb.urls')),
```

accounts **urls.py**

```
app_name = 'accounts'

urlpatterns = [
    path('login/', CustomLoginView.as_view(redirect_authenticated_user=True, template_name='accounts/login.html',
                                           authentication_form=LoginForm), name='login'),
    path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(template_name='accounts/logout.html'), name='logout'),
    path('registration/', RegisterView.as_view(), name='users-registration'),
    path('password-change/', ChangePasswordView.as_view(), name='password_change'),
    path('password_reset/', auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(), name='password_reset'),
    path('password_reset/done/', auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(), name='password_reset_done'),
    path('reset/<uidb64>/<token>/', auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(), name='password_reset_confirm'),
    path('reset/done/', auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(), name='password_reset_complete'),
]
```

turbineweb **urls.py**

```
app_name = 'turbineweb'

urlpatterns = [
    path('home/', views.home_page, name='home_page'),
]
```

Error:
[image]

Comment: If your question is solved, don't edit question but tick answer as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made a typo, it is `users-registration` and not `user-registration` :

```
<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'accounts:users-registration' %}">Register</a></li>
```